# Does wildcard % work in dependencies in Makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile

I tried below two ways but always getting (not getting "In nextFrag" printed):

> In ABC
>
> In Start

```
START : \
       test.ABC
       echo "In Start"

%.ABC : %.nextFrag
       echo "In ABC"

%.nextFrag:
       echo "In nextFrag"
```

#way 2:

```
START : \
       test.ABC
       echo "In Start"

%.ABC : $*.nextFrag
       echo "in ABC"

%.nextFrag:
       echo "In nextFrag"
```

Comment: I am new to Makefile, want to know how can I use wildcard for targets and dependencies.

Comment: Since the `%.nextFrag` rule has no prerequisites, any target that uses this pattern rule will be considered up to date if the file exists and will only be considered out of date (and rebuilt) if the target does not exist.  So, if you're not seeing `InNextFrag` printed then that means you have a file `test.nextFrag` that already exists on the disk, and so there's nothing make needs to do to create it.

Comment: The "way 2" example cannot work, because automatic variables like `$*` are _only_ available inside the recipe; you can't use them in the list of prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this is mostly specific to GNU `make`.)

`%` is not a wildcard (at least, not int he sense that `*`, `?`, and `[...]` are wildcards). It is used to define a so-called *pattern rule*, which is used for defining prerequisites only. In a pattern rule, `%` matches an arbitrary string, so `%.c` would mean "all *.c` files are prerequisites.

For what you are doing, where the patterns don't appear to match any files, you simply want to use *phony* targets, which are target names that don't correspond to any file.

```
.PHONY: START test.ABC nextFrag

START: test.ABC
        echo "In Start"

test.ABC: nextFrag
        echo "In ABC

nextFrag:
        echo "In nextFrag"
```